# Prove that $\frac{d}{dt} e^{A(t)} = (\frac{d}{dt}A(t)) e^A + \frac{1}{2}[A,\frac{d}{dt}A]e^A$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here, [.,.] is the comutator.

I am having a problem expanding the term $\frac{d}{dt}e^A(t)$, once matrix are non-comutative.

$$\frac{d}{dt}e^A(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{A^i}{i!})=(\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{d}{dt}A^i}{i!})$$
But what's $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt}A^i$? I mean, it can be either $iA'A^{i-1}$ or $A^{i-1}A'$.

Comment: Hint: product rule is still working here. So, for example, $\frac{d}{dt} A^{3} = A'AA   +  AA'A + AAA'$.

Comment: @Evgeny, I see that it helps, but I can't see how to get until the end.
$\frac{de^{A(t)}}{dt}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\sum_{k=0}^iA^{k-1}A'A^{i-k}}{i!}$ and then?

Comment: Indeed, it gets messy; you will probably want to use some version of Campbell-Hausdorff at some point. Your formula is not right (it's incomplete), see here for the correct version: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential